# Exception with text in Block -> Its Function -> Caller procedure way

Tags: oracle, exception

A procedure calls a function. It works with several tables, so I devided it to blocks. All blocks has its own exception section where the specific error message can be sent via e-mail.

Now I want to make the code cleaner and pass the exception in this order:
Block -> Its Function -> Caller Procedure

I can do it with 'raise' but in this case the caller procedure doesn't know where the exception came from.

Another solution I think is that the first block would use raise_application_error(User-Error-Id, 'Specific error message'). But in this case the original SQLCODE is hidden by raise_application_error.

How can I solve this?

I have something like this:

```
procedure main
...
begin
    v_pcs := calc_pcs(parameters);
exception
    When others then
        dbms_output.put_line(SCLCODE || ' - ' || SQLERRM);
        -- Here I'd like to read the part of the code where the exception happened
end;

funcion calc_pcs(
    parameters
) as
begin
    -- first block
    begin
        v_return := 5 / 0; -- just an example of an error
    exception
        when others then
            raise -- How to add text to predefined exception. For example 'FirstBlock || SqlErrM'
    end;
    ...
    rest of the code contains additional blocks with their exception handling and
    there is other code without blocks
    ...
    return v_return;
Exception
    when others then
        raise;
end;
```

Thanks Sayan! Sorry, but I may have missed something important in my previous post, let me clarify.
I want to concatenate a placeholder text to the original predefined exception string of the start block, for example "First Block" || "divisor is equal to zero". Further exception handling would pass this along with the SQLCODE unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```sql
declare
  e1 exception;
  e2 exception;
  e3 exception;
  pragma exception_init(e1, -20201);
  pragma exception_init(e2, -20202);
  pragma exception_init(e3, -20203);

  procedure func ( x int, txt varchar2 ) is
  begin
    case x
      when 1 then raise_application_error(-20201, 'x = ['||x||'] error text 1: ' || txt);
      when 2 then raise_application_error(-20202, 'x = ['||x||'] error text 2: ' || txt);
      when 3 then raise_application_error(-20203, 'x = ['||x||'] error text 3: ' || txt);
      else null;
    end case;
  end func;
begin -- main block:
  func(2, 'test');
exception
  when e1 then 
    dbms_output.put_line('e1');
    dbms_output.put_line(SQLCODE || ' - ' || SQLERRM);
  when e2 then 
    dbms_output.put_line('e2');
    dbms_output.put_line(SQLCODE || ' - ' || SQLERRM);
  when e3 then 
    dbms_output.put_line('e3');
    dbms_output.put_line(SQLCODE || ' - ' || SQLERRM);
end;
/
```

DBFiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/s7HeZpNB

dbms_output:

```sql
e2
-20202 - ORA-20202: x = [2] error text 2: test
```